# In clang, how do you use per-function optimization attributes?

Tags: c, clang, compiler-optimization

I'm trying to compile a specific function with no optimization using `clang`, in order to prevent certain security-related calls to `memset()` from being optimized away.

According to [the documentation that can be found here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html), there exists an `optnone` attribute which allows this. Also, [an example can be found here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html).

Unfortunately, (at least on the below version of `clang`, on OS X 10.9.5), this is causing compiler warnings, as can be seen in this example:

```
$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.51) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix

$ cat optnone.c
#include <string.h>

__attribute__((optnone)) void*
always_memset(void *b, int c, size_t len)
{
    return memset(b, c, len);
}

$ clang -Wall -O3 -c -o optnone.o optnone.c
optnone.c:3:16: warning: unknown attribute 'optnone' ignored [-Wattributes]
__attribute__((optnone)) void*
               ^
1 warning generated.
```

I also tried using `#pragma clang optimize off`, but this caused an `unknown pragma ignored` warning.

Does anyone know why this isn't working? Did I miss a prerequisite for using this feature? (I also tried using various different `-std=` parameters, including `c11`, `gnu11`, `c99`, and `gnu99`, but nothing changed the behavior.)

Comment: [works here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1eee116d09555879)

Comment: @BryanChen do you know what version of clang that is? I noticed it's being called via `clang++`. I tried that as well, but no change in my results.

Comment: It looks like this doesn't work with Apple's clang or llvm-gcc - [file a bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: [clang version 3.5.0 (tags/RELEASE_350/final 217394)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c12d3c91a4a97bb)

Comment: This question has a serious [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) going on. Turning off optimization is not a valid method for ensuring that sensitive data does not remain in memory. If that's what you want to do, you should post a new question about that (or search for an existing answer). It's an interesting (and much harder than it looks!) problem, and answers to it should not be buried in an unrelated question like this.

Comment: @R.., I disagree; this is a question about how to use a particular compiler feature in order to work around what is [arguably a compiler bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=8537). You are correct that whether or not a `memset()`-like construct is sufficient should be a separate question, but in this case it meets the requirement. Every other platform behaves correctly when a compiler-specific attribute is used to turn optimization off. (though validating that it meets the requirement isn't easy!)

Answer (score 9):

As advocated by @dulacc in his comment, `__attribute__ ((optnone))` works on clang 9.0.0 on Mac's High Sierra.

Comment: __attribute__((optnone)) works on Windows, but the result is rather inefficient because it turns off all optimizations. I really miss the more detailed control of optimizations that gcc has, such as __attribute__((optimize("-fno-unsafe-math-optimizations")))

Answer (score 7):

As clang documentation says,

> Clang supports GCC’s gnu attribute namespace. All GCC attributes which are accepted with the `__attribute__((foo))` syntax are also accepted as `[[gnu::foo]]`. This only extends to attributes which are specified by GCC (see the list of GCC function attributes, GCC variable attributes, and GCC type attributes). As with the GCC implementation, these attributes must appertain to the declarator-id in a declaration, which means they must go either at the start of the declaration or immediately after the name being declared.

Try

```
void* always_memset(void *b, int c, size_t len) [[gnu::optimize(0)]]
```

or

```
void* always_memset(void *b, int c, size_t len) __attribute__ ((optimize("0")));
```

Comment: You should try `__attribute__ ((optnone))` instead, `optimize("0")` is not defined on my machine