# Can I force gcc/clang to emit a function call, even when optimising?

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, clang, self-modifying

I have some code that runs x64 programs under ptrace and manipulates their code. For testing this sort of thing, I have a placeholder function in one of my test programs:

```
uint32_t __attribute__((noinline)) func(void) {
    return 0xCCCCCCCC;
}
```

The `0xCCCCCCCC` is then replaced at runtime with some other constant.

When I compile with clang and optimisation, though, clang replaces calls to the function with the constant `0xCCCCCCCC` (since the function is so simple). For example, here's part of the code generated for the call to check that the call to modified `TestFunc()` returns `0xCDCDCDCD`, which it should after having been modified:

```
movl    $3435973836, %edi       ## imm = 0xCCCCCCCC
movl    $3435973836, %eax       ## imm = 0xCCCCCCCC
leaq    16843009(%rax), %rdx    ## [16843009 = 0x01010101]
```

As you might imagine, this test then fails, because these two mismatching constant values won't match!

Can I force clang (and, hopefully in the same way, gcc...) to generate the function call?

(I don't want to disable optimisations globally - I already have a build that does that (and with that build, all tests pass). I'd just like to do a spot fix, if that's possible.)

Comment: Perhaps you could put the function body somewhere that is not visible to the code which might optimize it

Comment: That does work, but I'm a bit suspicious whole-program optimisation will see right through it! I'd feel safer with something that's more akin to a function call analogue of `volatile`.

Comment: Could you call it through a `volatile` function pointer?

Comment: Please report this to clang as a bug, they do mention the noinline attribute in http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html . And if they didn't support it, they should print a warning.

Answer (score 3):

Use attribute `optnone` or `optimize` to set the optimization level for `func` to `-O0`.

Only `optnone` is defined on my machine.  So the code for me is the following, but yours might use the header `__attribute__ ((optimize("0")))`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

uint32_t __attribute__ ((optnone)) func(void) {
    return 0xCCCCCCCC;
}

int main()
{
    return func();
}
```

See [In clang, how do you use per-function optimization attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266820/in-clang-how-do-you-use-per-function-optimization-attributes).