# Clang: Do not optimize a specific function

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, clang

For a long time i used `gcc` to compile C code. Sometimes i had to use the `optimize("O0")` attribute to disable optimizations for a specific function. Now i like to do this with `clang`.

Assume the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void __attribute__((optimize("O0"))) blabla(void) {
}

int main(void) {
    blabla();
    return 0;
}
```

If i compile it with `clang` i get this error:

```
test2.c:3:21: warning: unknown attribute 'optimize' ignored [-Wattributes]
void __attribute__((optimize("O0"))) blabla(void) {
                    ^
1 warning generated.
```

Then i used google (and also) stackoverflow to find out what attribute is required for `clang`, because many of them are not in the standard (as soon as i know).

I found this thread:
[In clang, how do you use per-function optimization attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266820/in-clang-how-do-you-use-per-function-optimization-attributes)

If i try the attribute `optimize("0")` i get this error:

```
test2.c:3:21: warning: unknown attribute 'optimize' ignored [-Wattributes]
void __attribute__((optimize("0"))) blabla(void) {
                    ^
1 warning generated.
```

And if i try the attribute `optnone` i get this error:

```
test2.c:3:21: warning: unknown attribute 'optnone' ignored [-Wattributes]
void __attribute__((optnone)) blabla(void) {
                    ^
1 warning generated.
```

I also tried to move the attribute after the function name, but it doesn't work (for some reason there is a warning about GCC?!):

```
test2.c:3:34: warning: GCC does not allow optnone attribute in this position on a function definition [-Wgcc-compat]
void blabla(void) __attribute__((optnone)) {
                                 ^
test2.c:3:34: warning: unknown attribute 'optnone' ignored [-Wattributes]
2 warnings generated.
```

Another test with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

[[clang::optnone]]
void blabla(void) {
}

int main(void) {
    blabla();
    return 0;
}
```

It produces:

```
user@ubuntu:/tmp/optxx$ clang test2.c
test2.c:3:1: error: expected identifier or '('
[[clang::optnone]]
^
test2.c:3:2: error: expected expression
[[clang::optnone]]
 ^
test2.c:8:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'blabla' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    blabla();
    ^
1 warning and 2 errors generated.
```

Probably i do something wrong, but i cannot see what.

-edit-

`clang` version:

```
user@ubuntu:/tmp/optxx$ clang -v
Ubuntu clang version 3.3-16ubuntu1 (branches/release_33) (based on LLVM 3.3)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: this should work. Which version of clang are you using? http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#optnone-clang-optnone

Comment: Almost duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26266820/841108) question

Comment: should be `void blabla(void) __attribute__((optnone)) {` I believe.

Comment: @Alex, not quite sure; the clang docs use `type __attribute__((stuff)) name` all over the place.

Comment: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#optnone-clang-optnone do you use -std=gnu maybe the attributes are only enabled if you declare your code as gnu code?

Comment: `-std=gnu` produeces an error (`error: invalid value 'gnu' in '-std=gnu'`) and `-std=gnu99` doesn't help (same errors as described in the post).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the following, clang-style attribute specification:

```
[[clang::optnone]]
void blabla(void);
```

**EDIT**: Clang 3.3 is pretty outdated. Use a more recent version, and your original `((optnone))` code will work.

Comment: Ok, i'll try to update clang:) Thanks for this hint.

Comment: Unfortunately it takes much time to upgrade ubuntu (and clang), but as soon as possible i'll test it:)