# Set higher optimisation level for a certain class template

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clang, compiler-optimization

I'm working on real-time audio processing projects built on top of the [JUCE framework](https://github.com/juce-framework/JUCE). To speed up some computational heavy algorithms with SIMD instructions, we use JUCE's cross-platform [SIMDRegister](https://github.com/juce-framework/JUCE/blob/master/modules/juce_dsp/containers/juce_SIMDRegister.h) wrapper. This leads to the desired increase in performance compared to non-SIMD optimised algorithms in optimised release builds but slows down the code extremely in debug builds so that it doesn't hit our real-time constraints anymore, making it useless when we need to debug algorithms.

This is likely due the highly templated nature of that class.

I wonder if it's possible to instruct the compiler to always optimise all calls to member functions of this class to the maximum level, no matter if in debug or release build? I'm willing to loose the ability to properly debug the parts of the code that call those functions, and it's okay for me if a solution would need modification of the JUCE sources since we maintain an in-house fork of the framework anyway.

I found `#pragma optimize` in the clang docs, but it seems to only decrease the optimisation level for the code wrapped in between.

I need a solution for clang and MSVC, however a clang-only solution would be an option since we are thinking of moving to clang for our Windows builds anyway.

Comment: Off the top of my head: You could explicitly instantiate the template's methods in separate TUs compiled with different flags.

Comment: Interesting. I want the release build to do as much inlining as possible, so this would mean that I need two versions of the class, one with the methods all defined inline for release builds and one with the methods all defined in a separate TU. As another approach, would you assume that it made a difference if left the SIMDRegister class as it is and instead took that approach on the actual implementations of the algorithms, that actually call the templated methods heavily? I imagine that the compiler would try to inline calls as much as possible if the TU is compiled with heavy optimisations

Comment: Have you tried GNU C `__attribute__((always_inline, optimize("O3")))` with clang?  That might have the same problem of only being able to decrease optimization level, IDK.  [Clang: Do not optimize a specific function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34902857) has more details on syntax for using it to set `-O0`, but setting `-O3` would hopefully also work.

Comment: @PeterCordes I just tried that but the compiler does not recognise that attribute. Any special flags to set along? I'm build with CMake, specifying the target property `CXX_STANDARD 20` which will probably apply `-std=c++20` on the target. I guess it would need `std=gnu++20` to work? Any idea how to apply that in a generic way via CMake?

Comment: If you're using `-std=c++20` instead of `gnu++20`, then yeah you have to use the namespace-safe versions of names like `__always_inline__` like they use in header files.  You'd obviously be using GNU features, though, so you might as well use `gnu++20` to save typing and visual noise.