# Is there a way to tell gcc/clang to put some block of code together?

Tags: c, gcc, clang

For some ugly reasons I will not discuss here I need to have some control on how my C compiler (gcc / clang) puts together the generated assembly for a function. Let us say that I have a block of code inside a function `f`, marked by a pair of labels `start` and `stop`:

```
void f() {
  ...
start:
   x = 0;
   y = -1;
   return;
stop:
  ...
}
```

I would like that the assembly generated for the above block were a contiguous sequence of instructions, as the C instructions are. But C compilers may choose to optimize, e.g., by sharing the assembly code for a same instruction if this is repeated many times in the source program. In the above example, if there were many other places in `f` where `y = -1; return`, it might be the case that the compiler decides to generate only one sequence of assembly instruction for this pair of C statements, and emit a jump instruction to it any time it finds a `y = -1; return`. Is there a way to prevent this other than enclosing the statements in a function (that would be very troublesome in my use case) or programming in assembly (that would defeat the purpose of using a high-level language when it is possible)? Or am I completely without hope?

Comment: _[Optimizations off for CLANG, GCC example here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32292725/645128)_.  But this alone may not force the  compiler to do what you want.

Comment: ... Also, these _[constraint keywords](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Simple-Constraints.html#Simple-Constraints)_ may help.

Comment: To make things harder, turning off optimizations might not be an option.

Comment: If you want to control the assembly code of your function, or part of it, then the natural solution is to write the code in (inline) assembly in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that this is really an X-Y problem, but inasmuch as you seem disinclined to discuss the reasons for wanting to do what you say, I'll respond to the question you actually asked.

You complain that writing the code in assembly would "defeat the purpose of using a high-level language", but that's in fact exactly what you are trying to do anyway.  If you care about details of the assembly code for your function, then you should write in assembly.  If you write in a higher-level compiled language then you are thereby saying that you're ok with the compiler choosing machine code details. In any event, other than disabling optimization (which anyway is not 100% guaranteed to do what you want), GCC and clang do not offer any way to exert the kind of control you describe over code generation from C source.

You do not necessarily need to write the whole function in assembly, however, and you certainly don't need to give up on C for the parts that do not require such fine control.  GCC / clang support *inline assembly*, with which you can write just those parts you care specially about in assembly.  To the best of my knowledge, you can rely on inline assembly to be treated as a black box -- not subject to any optimization, and not reordered with respect to surrounding code.